# Should I upgrade my client website from Laravel 4.0 to 4.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have client project which is running Laravel 4.0 currently. Last time I upgraded the system from Laravel 3 to 4 and it tooks a lot of times as there are a lot syntax changes. I wonder is it recommended to upgrade to avoid future incompatible issue? Does it compatible with laravel 4.0 packages?

p/s: this project hasn't ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you upgrade? it's your call.

If your project is working and you don't need the handful of new features then wait. If you really feel you need/want to then upgrade a few of your test projects first.

I've migrated several projects to 4.1, and the syntax issues are the least of your problems (although it is much easier than a Laravel 3 to 4 upgrade).

Even if you follow the upgrade guide exactly you may run into issues with Artisan and Composer choking on old compiled class loaders.

Before running `Composer update --no-scripts`, Run `artisan clear-compiled` or delete bootstrap/compiled.php

Also consider that many Laravel packages have not updated to 4.1, so check your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There are no big changes in Laravel 4.1. You can still use almost every features of Laravel 4.0 in Laravel 4.1 except the following:

- The current route is now accessed via Route::current() instead of Route::getCurrentRoute().
- Laravel now generates a single log file: app/storage/logs/laravel.log
- Password reminders have been overhauled for greater flexibility. You may examine the new stub controller by running the php artisan auth:reminders-controller Artisan command. You may also browse the updated documentation and update your application accordingly.
- Now routing is 100% faster

**Full upgrade guide:**

http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade